# Bat file that detect's when close an specific Excel workbook

Tags: windows, batch-file, command-line, cmd

I have this code that detects when the Excel.exe task is terminated:

```
:Excel
tasklist /nh /fi "imagename eq Excel.exe" | find /i "Excel.exe" >nul && (
goto Excel
) || (
goto Continue
)

:Continue
```

I want to modify this code to make it detect when I close an Excel workbook called

> Database.xlsm

This is beacause I need to close ALL the Excel workbooks that I have open in the moment I execute the batch to make it go to

> :Continue

I want it go to :Continue only when the Database.xlsm document is closed.

I hope you can help me. Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could try the following code, using [`findstr`](http://ss64.com/nt/findstr.html) to filter for the window title of the process:

```cmd
:Excel
timeout 1 /NOBREAK
tasklist /V /FI "IMAGENAME eq excel.exe" /FO LIST | findstr /RIXC:"Window Title: *Microsoft Excel - Database.xlsm" > nul && (
    goto :Excel
) || (
    goto :Continue
)
:Continue
```

You may need to adapt the partial string `Microsoft Excel - Database.xlsm` to your actual Excel window title.

I inserted `timeout 1 /NOBREAK` after line `:Excel` to avoid heavy CPU load.

Comment: Why use `/R` (regex) and `/C` (literal search string) together? I would think that they were mutually exclusive.

Comment: No, they are not; `/C` ensures the spaces to become part of the search string, `/R` defines the whole string as "regular expression" (as `/C` always defaults to literal mode); not using `/C` like `findstr [/R] "abc def"` actually defines two search strings `abc` and `def`; check out also [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/q/8844868)...

Answer (score 0):

try experiment with the `windowtitle` filter..

first use the `/V` flag to see teh window title.. then try filtering for it

ie

```
tasklist /v /FI "imagename eq Excel.exe" /FI "windowtitle eq Microsoft Excel - Database.xlsm"
```

it may/may not work depending on exact excel and windows versions

or you can filter afterwards using your `find`

Comment: The exact title in my case is "Database.xlsm - Excel" I tried this code but after close the Database.xlsm the CMD stuck in this part, so the command goes to :Excel all the time. Any other suggestion please? Thanks